# How to change the background color from selected text

Tags: html, css, background, selection

How can I change the background color from selected text? Like selecting this question but instead of a blue background and white text, a white background and red, blue, white etc. text.
Thanks, VVW

Answer (score 3):

You can use `::selection` CSS to achieve this.
Eg:

```css
::selection {
  background:#fff;
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3, you can use the `::selection` declaration.

```
::selection { background: #00FF00; }
```

Comment: If I press tab to select the textfield, there's still a lue background. Thans for responding, VVW

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but the easiest all use CSS. Read up on CSS background-color and CSS3 hover.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{
  background-color: #fff;
}
h1,p{
  color: #000;
}
::selection{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Trial </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> This is the trial header</h1>
  <p> This is the trial paragraph </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the`::selection` CSS pseudo-element.
for example:

```
p::selection {
 background:red;
}
```